# jquery nodename returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodename

This code isn't for anything in particular. I'm just trying to successfully get the tagName or nodeName of an element. However, when I run the following code, I always get an alert saying "undefined". I'm wondering if it's because this function executes when the document is ready? Is there a different place I should be doing this? Or is it probably my other javascript code conflicting somehow (I would doubt).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#first').hover(function() {
            alert($('#last').nodeName);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are trying to access a non-member of the `jQuery` object. 
Use one of these DOM element accessors to retrieve these properties:

`$( '#last' ).get(0).nodeName`

**OR**

`$( '#last' )[0].nodeName`

**OR**

`document.getElementById( 'last' ).nodeName`

Comment: I don't think this works anymore and has been depreciated. Steven's answer worked fine: .prop("nodeName"))

Comment: Two comments for @newUserNameHere: (1) The answer does work and the functions used are not deprecated. (2) Note the difference between "deprecated" (correct) and "depreciated" (incorrect), as discussed in [this other Stack Exchange question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45295).

Answer (score 65):

Use the `prop()` of jQuery:

```
alert($('#last').prop("nodeName"));
```