# Why this jquery selector giving uncaught exception: in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, selector

I'm populating the results div with images from jsonp call. The images are displayed like

```
<li><img class="abs" src"..."/></li> 
<li><img class="abs" src"..."/></li> 
<li><img class="abs" src"..."/></li> 
...
```

I'm using the following jquery code to do a simple task such as displaying the tag name when an image with .abs is clicked on This should return IMG. But instead i am getting `uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #` in firefox firebug. What am i doing wrong.

```
$('.abs').live('click',function(){
    console.log(this.nodeName);
});
```

Comment: is the jsonp badly formatted?

Comment: I don't think that code would cause that error.  Is it possible that there's some other code nearby?

Comment: Its working fine for me.. Is there any other JS code that is stripped out?

Comment: Please post actual code that reproduces the issue. If that's your actual HTML, you're using invalid markup.

Comment: my html results as i see them in firebug looks exactly as i have it above with <li/> and <img/> regadless to whether it's coming from a jsonp call or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick search and this came up:
[jquery nodename returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770207/jquery-nodename-returning-undefined)

From that post:

> You are trying to access a non-member
>   of the jQuery object. Use one of these
>   DOM element accessors to retrieve
>   these properties:
>
> `$( '#last' ).get(0).nodeName`
>
> OR
>
> `$( '#last' )[0].nodeName`
>
> OR
>
> `document.getElementById('last').nodeName`

Comment: OP is doing `this.nodeName` which is equivalent. All the methods you gave are asking for the `nodeName` property on a DOM element. In the handler for `live()`, `this` is a DOM element as well.

Comment: Ok it worked after i renamed class name on the images from abs to abss. Cannot figure out why the class abs would throw this error. I do have .abs on other image elements on the page.